# is there any way to use code get from script and use it at php?

Tags: php, html, ajax

i am making a thing like livesearch
my table is this

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>barcode</th>
<th>name</th>
</tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" id="fk_ColCode" onKeyDown="search()"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="fk_ColName" disabled></td></tr>
</table>
```

script

```
<script>
function search(){
var barcode=document.getElementById('fk_ColCode').value;
document.getElementById('fk_colName').value = <?php 
$select_1="select colName FROM colacc WHERE ColCode='barcode'";
if($select_2=mysql_query($select_1))
while($select_3=mysql_fetch_array($select_2)) {
print $select_3["colName"]; }?>
}
```

i need to change value `fk_ColName` `onkeydown`.

Comment: Sidenote: you should be using Ajax for this. Injecting MySQL in like that, well... it just makes things more difficult.

Comment: i think it can be done with a litle change :D ( not sure)

Comment: You cannot call php code inside Javascript. You should use an Ajax request, as mentioned @Fred-ii-

Comment: your user will request a url and get html/css/javascript, which all run client-side.  They won't have php installed in their browser and you wouldn't want them to have your db credentials anyway, it's a server-side language and your php/mysql happens on the server.  Use ajax to send a request to another php page, pick up the values, and do the query server-side.

Comment: i dont know ajax if you can help me how change this to get livesearch.